# Multiple SSL environment using CRYPTO_thread_setup

Tags: c++, multithreading, openssl

I have multiple SSL servers runnings in different threads, I'm having trouble defining locking methods in openssl c++ ? Should I define one locking/cleanup method for whole application or multiple i.e. per thread ?

Answer (score 1):

Init library once in main application thread, just like here: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/threads/mttest.c#L331 or the same thing in samples here: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/tree/master/crypto/threads

Comment: links are broken

Comment: thank you for the feedback, you can find all the relevant source code in the jww answer right here.
but this answers are outdated now https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2017/02/21/threads/

Answer (score 1):

> Should I define one locking/cleanup method for whole application or multiple i.e. per thread ?

OpenSSL does *not* utilize thread local storage. So you should *not* attempt to install locks on a per-thread basis.

You should provide the locks application-wide.

---

Here's the relevant source.

```
$ grep -R CRYPTO_thread_setup *
crypto/threads/th-lock.c: * CRYPTO_thread_setup();
crypto/threads/th-lock.c:void CRYPTO_thread_setup(void)
...
```

And here's one example of the setup (there are a few of them for different platforms):

```
static HANDLE *lock_cs;
...

void CRYPTO_thread_setup(void)
    {
    int i;

    lock_cs=OPENSSL_malloc(CRYPTO_num_locks() * sizeof(HANDLE));
    for (i=0; i<CRYPTO_num_locks(); i++)
        {
        lock_cs[i]=CreateMutex(NULL,FALSE,NULL);
        }

    CRYPTO_set_locking_callback((void (*)(int,int,char *,int))win32_locking_callback);
    /* id callback defined */
    return(1);
    }
```

Notice there's one set of locks used across the application.

Comment: so, what about the comment "id callback defined" ? does it mean it's not needed for Windows ? it's not clear from the code